# Acknowledging multiple messages with Rabbit.js for RabbitMQ

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, message-queue

I'm using RabbitMQ as a buffer for a large number of messages that need to be saved to a database. The messages come in, then on the other end, a script pulls a number of them and writes them, as a batch, to the database. This app is written in NodeJS (using Rabbit.js).

While I haven't found a way to wait, and consume a set number of messages at once (say, 100), I am using a worker queue to receive messages in Node, and then write them after a time period / max number of messages has been reached.

If the app dies, however, or otherwise fails, I need the messages to be re-released onto the queue.

Therefore I can use the `ack()` function in Rabbit.js on the queue, but that merely acknowledges the most recent message, instead of letting me select a number of messages to acknowledge, and I'm reluctant to call `ack()` 100 times just to get to the right number of acknowledgements.

Is there a way to acknowledge receipt of X messages using Rabbit.js (or some other  Node.js library that will work with RabbitMQ)?